# Making a scope that uses scopes from its associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I want to know how to make a scope, that uses the scope of its associations. Let me give you an example. (I hope you do not find it contrived)

I have a model `Wife` and `Husband`. The husband has a scope that, based on several of his attributes, filters `good` husbands.

How could I build now a scope on `Wife` to filter all the wives that have `good` husbands?

```
class Wife
    #Sorry for how that sounds
    belongs_to :husband

    scope :with_good_husband, -> { ???? }
end

class Husband
    scope :good, -> { ...whatever... }
end
```

Comment: I would probably go with two queries here: `where(husband_id: Husband.good.pluck(:id))`. You could probably go with some clever join and merge, however I would be very careful when using joins in a scope. There is always an option to use a database view.

Comment: This solution works. Thanks. Put it out of the comments and into an "Answer", and I will accept it :)

Comment: `scope :with_good_husband, -> { joins(:husband).where(husband: Husband.good) }`. Although @BroiSatse is right, scopes with joins tend to get real messy fast since its hard to know what you actually need from the model layer. You can also use [association extensions](https://railsadventures.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/activerecord-association-extensions/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, I go with two queries to free your scope from joins (which are really hard to operate later on due to some associations magic happening in some methods):

```
scope :with_good_husband, -> { where(husband_id: Husband.good.pluck(:id)) }
```